# Где можно посмотреть какими файлами обменивается 1с с битрикс при интеграции?

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интеграция

Где можно посмотреть какими файлами обменивается 1с с битрикс при интеграции? Сколько искал, нужного не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте посмотреть файлы в папке: `/upload/1c_exchange и /upload/1c_catalog`.

Интеграция с 1С: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=1158

Стандартный обмен осуществляется через `/bitrix/admin/1c_exchange.php`, где размещена ссылка на `/bitrix/modules/sale/admin/1c_exchange.php`. В этот файл приходит информация из 1С и в зависимости от "этапа" отправляется в тот или иной компонент для обработки. Соответственно можно расставить "ловушки" и "посмотреть" какая информация приходит на каком этапе, в какой компонент отправляется и в самом компоненте увидеть как она обрабатывается.